# Count event then using throttle/debounce to execute event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

How do I use underscore throttle/debounce in angular to count event triggered x-times. Then after a certain interval trigger the event with the knowledge of x?

html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testC">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="add()" value="add"></input>
    {{counter}}
</div>
```

js

```
function testC($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.counter++;
    }

    /*

        counter x-timed add has triggered
      after interval has been reached trigger a event that does $scope.counter = $scope.counter + x

   */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6w747zzL/

Comment: `_.throttle` is not for triggering every _x-times_, but for triggering at the most once per every  _x-milliseconds_

Comment: Yes, but lets say the function add has a counter and a call to a function in a throttle. Then It will work. But how do I write that in angular?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6w747zzL/1/ (Try to click fast on the button)

Comment: There should be code in the question that explains it without clicking on jsfiddle link. Without `Example` code the form should clearly say, **Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code**. Please, don't cheat message validator.

Comment: Whats wrong with my jsfiddle example? The jsfiddle is just a proof of concept. My real code is kinda heavy and irrelevant.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho He's right, you should include the code in your question because it helps other users to read the question and understand it immediately without going to external links. So please edit it (You can also take a look at the link I posted in my previous comment and see if it helps)

Comment: The answerers don't have to click on jsfiddle link to familiarize themselves with your code. It should be in the question. That's why a post can't physically be submitted on SO if there is jsfiddle link and no code. You've cheated the system by making `Example` word a code. Regarding 'heavy and irrelevant', see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @AlonEitan something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6w747zzL/1/ but I don't get it to clear the counter and transfer the counter to submitted each time I stop pressing it. I've to invoke a new chain of events to transfer the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, you use throttle to call a "heavy duty" function every X-miliseconds, so this is how you do it:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testC">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="add()" value="add">
    counter: {{counter}} <br>
    throttle: {{ throttle }}<br>
    non-throttle: {{ nonthrottle }}
</div>

function testC($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.counter = 0;
   $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.counter++;
   }

   $scope.throttle = 0;
   $scope.$watch('counter', _.throttle(function(value) {
        // Wrapping this in '$timeout' will ensure a digest cycle execute that will update the view (Since underscore is not native angular function)
        $timeout(function() {
             $scope.throttle++;
        });
   }, 500));

   $scope.nonthrottle = 0;
   $scope.$watch('counter', function(value) {
     $scope.nonthrottle++;
   });
}
```

You should click fast on the button and you'll see that the throttle watcher doesn't update every time you click the button, but only once at the most in every 500ms.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6w747zzL/2/

Comment: Thanks, im using something similair. But I think in this case debounce is better than throttle..

Comment: @PresidentCamacho Then you can use `_.debounce` but don't forget to inject `$timeout` and wrap the code when you update view related properties, it will trigger a digest cycle and will update the view (I have updated my answer and included `$timeout`)